# Select all worksheets with prefix, copy and paste data

Tags: excel, vba

i have a little project in excel with VBA but i have question, how to select all worksheets with prefix and how to copy from selected worksheets tables to one new ?

```
 Sub Svod_table()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Ranges
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Fist age" Then
        If sh.name Like "1c.*" Then
        With sh
        .Select
        End With 
        End If
    End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you want the data from the selected sheets copied?

Comment: I want to copy and paste in turn from each for 1 worksheet

Comment: So the data from each worksheet would be copied below the data from the previous  worksheet?

Comment: The data would be copied from each to new one sheet and i have N-numer sheets from what i want to copy data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will consolidate the grades into one sheet with a column for each subject.

```
Sub Svod_table()
Dim shNew As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        'If ComboBox1.Value = "Fist age" Then
            If sh.name Like "1c.*" Then
            
                If shNew Is Nothing Then
                    Set shNew = Sheets.Add
                    Set rngDst = shNew.Range("A1")
                    Set rngSrc = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    rngSrc.Copy rngDst
                    Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(, rngSrc.Columns.Count)
                Else
                    Set rngSrc = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Columns(rngSrc.Columns.Count)
                    rngSrc.Copy rngDst
                    Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(, 1)
                End If

            End If
        'End If
    Next sh
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will copy the data from every sheet with a name starting with '1c.*' to a new sheet, one below the other.

It assumes each of the sheets is structured the same and have the same heading.

```
Sub Svod_table()
Dim shNew As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If ComboBox1.Value = "Fist age" Then
            If sh.Name Like "1c.*" Then
            
                If shNew Is Nothing Then
                    Set shNew = Sheets.Add
                    Set rngDst = shNew.Range("A1")
                    Set rngSrc = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                Else
                    Set rngSrc = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1).Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count - 1)
                End If

                rngSrc.Copy rngDst

                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(rngSrc.Rows.Count)

            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, and have question, if i want to place new datas to new colum what i need change in this code

Comment: ok, i want to add new data to new columns with headers, for example Fist Name, Group, Subj1,Sub2 and etc.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add headers for new columns in the newly created sheet?

Comment: For example, i have table with subject with has First Name, Groupe and Name of Subj and i want to copy these datas to new sheet without repeats the first and secont columns, just add N-number columns and copy and paste datas it woud be like First Name, Group, Subj1, Subj2, ..., etc

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain what you are trying to do in more detail, perhaps post some sample data, or even a link to a workbook with sample data.

Comment: yeap, sure https://dropmefiles.com/Dhs9E It's grades table with students and their subject, i want to unite N-numbers table to one with all subjects

Comment: Is the last column on each sheet the grade for the subject?